# Create json object for each scenario

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-behave

Tried with below command:

```
behave sample.feature --format json --out file_name.json
```

The above command provides a single json file containing all the scenarios results. But I need multiple json's for all the listed scenarios present in feature file instead of a single json.
Is there any implemented logic to get this or anything to add here.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as is, but it can be done. There are two main options.

**1)** You could create your own formatter class to achieve this, or possibly expand the already existing JSON formatter. See [this](https://pythonhosted.org/behave/new_and_noteworthy_v1.2.5.html#user-defined-formatters) for more details on user defined formatters.

**2)** Post-processing the output. You basically could create your own little tool that post-processes the generated JSON file after your tests have finished executing.

Comment: Thanks Verv for your inputs